# MSBuild.exe (return code was -1066598274)

Tags: msbuild

NAnt build script fails with this message

External Program Failed: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe (return code was -1066598274)

What can this mean?

Comment: What is your source control repository?  SVN?  Does the script call SVN to get the code?

Comment: SVN is used. TeamCity configuration updates code before build.

Comment: It looks like server wasn't rebooted after some upgrades. Script works correctly after rebooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVN "getting" sometimes get out of whack.

1. Reboot.

If that doesn't work:

1. Login as the identity that is causing the issue above.
2. Issue a **svn.exe list** command (or anything, but 'list' is the easiest) and make sure you have the certificate downloaded correctly. (as in, from the command line)

Basically, do some basic stuff to correct the svn "getting".